# Don't know what to do

Tags: geometry

In the family R of all triangle on the same base whose areas are all equal prove that the isosceles triangle in R has the least perimeter

Answer (score 5):

This would be fairly routine as a calculus problem, but here's a proof using just elementary geometry.  Let the fixed base be the line segment $XY$ of length $b$, and let the fixed area be $A$. Then if $XYZ$ is any triangle in R, its height $h$ satisfies $A=\frac12bh$, so $h$ is also fixed.  That is, $Z$ must lie on a line $l$ that is parallel to $XY$ and at a distance $h$ from $XY$.  Let $X'$ be the reflection of $X$ in $l$.  The perimeter of $XYZ$, which we want to minimize, is $b+XZ+ZY$ (where I'm using notation like $XZ$ for the length of this line segment); as $b$ is fixed, we want to minimize $XZ+ZY$.  But, by symmetry (in view of the definition of $X'$), $XZ=X'Z$, and so we want to minimize $X'Z+ZY$.  That's the total length of a path from $X'$ to $Y$, crossing $l$ at $Z$, and otherwise straight.  Since the shortest path between two points is a straight line, the length of that path is minimized when it is straight, i.e., when $Z$ is collinear with $X'$ and $Y$.  But that means (by symmetry again) that $XZY$ is an isosceles triangle.

Comment: Can you just add a diagram

Comment: No, diagrams in LaTeX are beyond my capabilities.

Comment: Got it bro I got the answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is an illustration for **Andreas Blass**'s answer:

[image]

Here is another approach which may be taken without using tools from calculus.  As described in his answer, we can use a fixed base of length $ \ b \ $ for the triangle, with the vertex opposite that base at a (perpendicular) distance $ \ h \ $ away from the base.  This gives us a constant area $ \ A \ = \ \frac{1}{2}  bh \ $ for the triangle, and also means that we wish to place this vertex so that the minimal perimeter $ \ b \ + \ s_1 \ + \ s_2 \ $ is obtained.  As $ \ b \ $ is constant, it is then the sum $ \ s_1 \ + \ s_2 \ $ we seek to minimize.

[image]

We can divide the base into two segments of lengths $ \ \mu \ b \ $ and $ \ (1-\mu) \ b \ $ , with $ \ \mu \ $ taking values in the interval $ \ 0 \ \le \ \mu \ \ \le \ \frac{1}{2} \ $ .  [Using values in $ \ \frac{1}{2}  < \ \mu \ \le  \ 1 \ $ is equivalent to working with the "mirror image" of a triangle with $ \ \mu \ ' \ = \ (1 - \mu) \ $ .   ]

The "adjustable" altitude in this triangle divides it into two smaller right triangles, for which $ \ s_1 \ $ and $ \ s_2 \ $ are the lengths of the hypotenuses.  We can thus write

$$ s_1 \ + \ s_2 \ = \ \sqrt{h^2 \ + \ (\mu \ b)^2} \ + \  \sqrt{h^2 \ + \ ( \ [1 - \mu] \ b \ )^2}$$

$$ = \ h \ \left[ \ \sqrt{1  \ + \  \mu^2 \left( \frac{b}{h} \right)^2} \ + \  \sqrt{1 \ + \   [1 - \mu]^2 \ \left( \frac{b}{h} \right)^2} \ \ \right] $$

$$ = \ h \ \left[ \ \sqrt{1  \ + \  \mu^2 \left( \frac{b}{h} \right)^2} \ + \  \sqrt{ \ [ \ 1  \ + \  \mu^2 \left( \frac{b}{h} \right)^2 \ ] \ + \   (1 \ - \ 2 \mu) \left( \frac{b}{h} \right)^2} \ \ \right] \ \ , $$

multiplying out the binomial square under the second radical on the second line, and then rearranging terms under that radical on the third line.  The second radical is larger than the first one for $ \ 0 \ \le \ 2 \mu \ < \ 1 \ \Rightarrow \ 0 \ < \ (1 - 2 \mu) \ \le \ 1 $ ; the two radicals are only equal, making their sum as small as possible, for $ \ 2 \mu \ = \ 1 \ \Rightarrow \ \mu \ = \ \frac{1}{2} \ $ .  For that value of $ \ \mu \ $ , the altitude bisects the base and $ \ s_1 \ = \ s_2 \ $ , so the triangle with the minimal perimeter is *isoceles* with

$$ s_1 \ + \ s_2 \ = \ 2 \ \sqrt{h^2 \ + \ \frac{b^2}{4}} \ \ . $$

(We may observe that related arguments based on trigonometry lead to a similar result, still leaving us to deal with these radicals.)

[image]

Note that if we place a second identical triangle "base-to-base and flipped right-for-left" against our first triangle, we have also proved the corollary that the parallelogram of constant area with the smallest perimeter is a *rhombus*.  (The rhombus will be a *square* for $ \ b \ = \ 2h \ $ .)